# Using 1 IR receiver for 4 LED controllers

Tags: led, infrared, led-strip, remote-control

I've purchased 4 cheap LED controllers from China for controlling 20m LED stripes.
After setting the system up, I encountered the problem that at least 1 of the 4 LED controllers doesn't respond to the signal from the IR remote.

This is a real problem if I want to turn them off, because 1 out of 4 doesn't turn off and if I press the ON/OFF button again, it may turn off - BUT - the other 3 LEDs turn on again.

The controllers look like this: [image]

So I had the idea to remove 3 of the IR antennas and only use 1 IR antenna for all 4 LED controllers.

Here's the schematic for this:

[image: schematic]

The problem: It doesn't really work (well it did for ~10 minutes). Now the LEDs are not lighting up anymore.

Is my circuit wrong or have my LED controllers gone broken? (The LEDs are fine - i tested it with a different LED controller)

Comment: *remove 3 of the IR antennas and only use 1 IR antenna* **Why** would you not simply assume that the non-responding controller must be broken or responds differently to the remote's commands? IR does not use an antenna, it uses an IR **receiver**. Combining all receivers into one can give all kinds of issues if you're not careful like the grounds not being common. Besides, there is no need to combine the receivers into one. It is the microcontroller in the driver that decodes the commands, not the receiver. Chances are you damaged the drivers.

Comment: Thank you. I think my problem is that there is no common ground for the IR receiver. This maybe damaged all LED controllers :-(

Answer (score 1):

They are "cheap", why do you expect them to work?

> I think my problem is that there is no common ground for the IR
>   receiver. This maybe damaged all LED controllers

Not likely. You just need a simple troubleshooting procedure to isolate the problem part. IF they all work individually there is very few reasons a four will not work.  Either the PSU or IR receiver.

---

Try the strips one at a time to ensure they all work.
Use red only at a dimmed level. (lowest wattage to test PSU)
Then add one at a time , testing after adding another all with dimmed red.

If it only fails when adding the fourth strip, disconnect the working IR receiver from the working LED controllers.  The problem may be the receiver cannot driver 4 controllers.

If none fail then change the color to white  and increase the intensity (highest wattage).

The method to my madness is that if the strips work individually then nothing is broken.  Then you must isolate the problem to the IR receiver drive capability or the PSU (varying intensity).